# Unknown column <tablename>_id on Shopware 6 translations

Tags: shopware, shopware6

After creating a Shopware6 Entity with translations,
exactly following the [official tutorial](https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-platform-dev-en/how-to/indepth-guide-bundle/entity-translation?category=shopware-platform-dev-en/how-to/indepth-guide-bundle),
I get an `Unknown column "<tablename>_id"` error; the tablename seems to be interpreted as part of the column name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a requirement on the naming scheme of mapped fields in the *_translation tables:
they HAVE to follow <tablename>_id. That is, the tablename IS part of the fieldname.

In the tutorial that's not obvious, since they speak of bundle_id, where "bundle" is not the name of the entity but the table name. Most likely you vendor-prefixed and modulename-prefixed your table.

Example:

```
Your Entity: ACME\CoolModule\Core\Content\FoobarDefinition

Entity Table:
acme_coolmodule_foobar

Translation-table HAS to be exactly:
          CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `acme_coolmodule_foobar_translation` (            
          `acme_coolmodule_foobar_id` BINARY(16) NOT NULL,
          `language_id` BINARY(16) NOT NULL, ...
```

The difficulty is that Shopware doesn't SWAG-Prefix their own tutorial-modules, so you can't see the difference.